# How to use insert into a table using a select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Below is my PL/SQL block, where I want to insert records by selecting form another table, bad on variables I've populated.

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR cust_insert is
    select distinct UBAN,SUBSCRIBER_NO from not_exists_inv_RC_CINF;

  i_cust_id    varchar2(100);
  i_sub_no     varchar2(100);

Begin

  dbms_output.enable(2000000);

  Open cust_insert; 
  Loop  
    Fetch cust_insert into i_cust_id,i_sub_no;
    Exit when cust_insert%NOTFOUND; 

    dbms_output.put_line('CUSTOMER IS :- '||i_cust_id
      ||' SUBSCRIBER IS :- '||i_sub_no);

    insert into not_exists_inv_RC_CINF_TRB
    select a.MST_TRX_ID,entity_id 
    from lspappc.trb9_mst_log_1v a, lspappc.trb1_actv b 
    where a.ACTV_CODE_ID=b.ACTV_CODE_ID
    and PART_DEP_ENT like 'CUSTOMER=i_cust_id'
    and general_data_c like '%i_sub_no%'
    and a.ACTV_CODE_ID=44;

    commit;
  END LOOP;

  Close cust_insert;   
End;
/
```

The data is not getting inserted in table, can you explain why?

Comment: This part of the insert statement seems to be not well formed `PART_DEP_ENT like 
   'CUSTOMER=i_cust_id'` did you mean  `PART_DEP_ENT like '%' || i_cust_id || %'`

Answer (score 4):

You're treating the PL/SQL variables as string literals; this:

```
general_data_c like '%i_sub_no%'
```

should be:

```
general_data_c like '%' || i_sub_no || '%'
```

I'm not sure quite what you're trying to do with:

```
PART_DEP_ENT like 'CUSTOMER=i_cust_id'
```

as there are no wild cards and the construct looks odd anyway; you might want:

```
PART_DEP_ENT = 'CUSTOMER=' || l_cust_id
```

... but that's less clear.

With the literal values you have, though, there are no matching records in the table you're selecting from - remember, you're looking for the string `'i_sub_no'`, not the value of the `i_sub_no' variable.